# How to reach outside the class and break class from continue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, es6-class

i want to break the class and end up the class from continuing whenever class ran in to problem and return me the specified error.

```js
class OnlineVisitors {
    constructor() {
        // get VisitorIP
        this.fetchIP().then(ip => this.IP = ip).catch(err=>{
            return err
        });
    }
    async fetchIP() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            await axios.get('https://api.ipgeolocation.io/getip')
                .then(res => resolve(res.data.ip))
                .catch(error=>{
                    if (error.response) {
                        return reject(this.ErrorModel({
                            message:'The request was made and the server responded with error',
                            sourceCode:'getIPRequest',
                            errorDetail:error.response.data
                        }))
                        } else if (error.request) {
                        return reject(this.ErrorModel({
                            message:'The request was made but no response was received',
                            sourceCode:'getIPRequest',
                            errorDetail:error.request
                        }))
                        } else {
                        return reject(this.ErrorModel({
                            message:'Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error',
                            sourceCode:'getIPRequest',
                            errorDetail:error.message
                        })) 
                    }
                })
        })
    }
}
```

in the above code,i want to class return me my custom error and don't continue whenever cant receive the IP from outside. but it didn't return the error and it continue the class with error. what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor, you can't return the error, instead of that use directly your fetchIP method

```
let x = new OnlineVisitors()
         .fetchIP()
         .then()
          .catch((err) => {
             //handle the err 
          })
```

Comment: i don't want to show it like error i want to break the class and show the message that i defined already,what can i do about this?

Comment: Take in count that you can't return anything in your constructor, I think to use directly your `fetchIp` method after initialize should works.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with try/catch. Eg:

```
  1 const axios = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject({ response:  "Error wirh" }), 2000));
  2 
  3 class SimpleClass {
  4         async fetchIp() {
  5           console.log("Tests");
  6           try {
  7             return await axios();
  8           } catch (e) {
  9             if (e.response) {
 10                 // do anything
 11                return new Error("Error on response");
 12             } else if (e.request) {
 13                 // do anything
 14             } else {
 15                 // do anything
 16             }
 17           }
 18         }
 19 }       
 20 
 21 new SimpleClass().fetchIp()
 22   .then(res => console.log(res))
 23   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```